# No module named 'qiskit.optimization' on Google Colab

Tags: qiskit, programming

I have qiskit installed in my colab runtime and can import qiskit, but I can not import anything from `qiskit.optimization`. Am I missing something?

EDIT:
It seems that `qiskit.optimization` uses `qiskit-aqua`. Installing aqua resolved the import issues.

Answer (score 1):

Run `!pip install qiskit-optimization` to install it and import it as `qiskit_optimization`. Read more about the framework on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-optimization).

Comment: Im trying to use `qiskit.optimization.applications.ising.stable_set.get_operator()` from the [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.19/stubs/qiskit.optimization.applications.ising.stable_set.html) here, but there doesn't seem to be an analogue in this package. Have you seen this before?

Comment: @MudiYang I think you can use the [`StableSet`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/optimization/stubs/qiskit_optimization.applications.StableSet.html#qiskit_optimization.applications.StableSet) object, convert it into a `QuadraticProgram` and then use the [`to_ising()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/optimization/stubs/qiskit_optimization.QuadraticProgram.to_ising.html#qiskit_optimization.QuadraticProgram.to_ising) method.